# Overloading operator() and getting "lvalue required as unary '&' operand"

Tags: c++, overloading, pass-by-reference, operator-keyword

I have a matrix class for which I am overloading the `operator()` to access its (row, column) values.

Here is a synthesized version of the class header:

```
template<typename T>
class mat4
{
  public:
    T m[4][4];
...
    T  operator()(int i, int j) const;
    T& operator()(int i, int j);
...

}
```

and its implementation:

```
...

template<typename T>
T mat4<T>::operator()(int i, int j) const
{
  return m[i][j];
}

template<typename T>
T& mat4<T>::operator()(int i, int j)
{
  return m[i][j];
}
...
```

I am trying to pass the first index of this array as the last argument to the function `glUniformMatrix4fv`, but if I use the following syntax:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, uniformName.c_str()), 1, GL_TRUE, &data(0,0));
```

I get the error **"lvalue required as unary '&' operator"**. The way I've been able to get around this was to access the `m` member variable directly, through:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, uniformName.c_str()), 1, GL_TRUE, &data.m[0][0]);
```

but I'd like to know if there's a way around this using the overloaded operator directly.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `const` versions returns by value, i.e. an rvalue.

Comment: Consider `const T& operator()(int i, int j) const;`

Comment: @NathanOliver why is it using my ```const``` version as opposed to the one defined with ```T& mat4<T> ...```?

Comment: @luismsfern We can't say without a [mre].  If I had to guess, you either declared your matrix as `const` or you are in a function where the matrix was passed in as a `const matrix&` parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand now. I'm fairly new to C++ and still grasping some of these concepts. Indeed, removing the ```const``` attribute from the matrix as it's passed onto the function that calls ```glUniformMatrix4fv``` seems to work.

Comment: @DrewDormann I suppose you're suggesting modifying the ```const``` version of the operator to match what you described. Would there be any advantage in having the ```const``` version return by value instead of by reference?

Comment: @luismsfern I am only aware of _disadvantages_ in returning by value.  It creates a copy when a copy may not be needed.  Depending on what `T` is, it may return something that is deceptively assignable (a bug).  It creates "lvalue required" errors, as you have discovered.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks for your comment. I'm used to Fortran where things are passed by reference by default, so I share the same perspective.